# How to load an image in Paint.NET?

Tags: windows-10, paint.net

I'm having problems loading the How To Guide. I'm a first-time visitor and I just need to use resizing tools in Paint.NET, but I don't know where or how to load images.

Comment: The same way you load a file in any other software. File>open

Answer (score 0):

To open an image for editing in Paint.NET, from the Paint.NET menu select *File* -> *Open* and then browse to the image you want to open.

[image]

To resize an image, from the Paint.NET menu select *Image* -> *Resize* to open a *Resize* window. Make sure that the *Maintain aspect ratio* checkbox is checked so the image will be resized without getting distorted. Set your height, width and resolution to the values that you want and click the *OK* button.